# Text Adjust to Fit in code?

Tags: iphone, xcode, text, uilabel

Is there an equivalent of Adjust to Fit for UILabel text created dynamically in Xcode?
ie:

```
UILabel *someLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 35, 18)];                                   
someLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
someLabel.FOO_SIZETOFIT = YES; //FOO CODE
[someLabel release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line

```
someLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you! I searched for AdjustFont, AdjustText ... but not with an "s". Much appreciated!

Comment: and use documentation to find out such things, then there won't be any chance to miss out something.  :)